# How to pass a guid parameter to viewmodel constructor in silverlight 4 using MVVM Light

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I need to pass an id to my viewmodel constructor. This id is external, it is passed to the webpage that contains the silverlight app. I am using the MVVM Light framework.
I have seen several articles about passing parameters to the viewmodel, but in all of them the parameter is something that is global or that can be instantiated with no parameters.
In my case I need a GUID id in the constructor of my viewmodel and it's passed from another app.

EDIT:

This is the code of the locator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator(Guid id)
    {
        Container = new UnityContainer();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up all the resources.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        Container.Resolve<CautelaVM>().Cleanup();
    }


    #region Cautela Inventário

    public CautelaVM CautelaInventario
    {
        get
        {
            return Container.Resolve<CautelaVM>();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The locator is passed to the DataContext in the view like this:

DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}

EDIT 2:

Now it works. This is the code I added in the view ctor for registering the GUID to be used in the VM ctor:

```
ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.Container.RegisterType<CautelaVM>(new InjectionConstructor(id));
```

Comment: Why can't you use property injection?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Can you point me in the right direction? I'm not very experienced in silverlight and/or MVVM.

Comment: It's not mvvm related. You construct your object first and then set the guid using a property or an Initialize(Guid) method

Comment: @dan with your insights I've been investigating on this and this is where I am, so far. My viewmodel has the Id property and I also have a RelayCommand that sets the Id. Now I am trying to bind this command to the onload of the view so that it sets the id of the viewmodel when it loads. I think this is where you were pointing me at. Now the problem is how to pass the parameter to the RelayCommand. The parameter id comes from the webpage that contains the silverlight. How do I get the id from the view to the viewmodel, still leaving both completly decoupled?

Comment: What about my answer?

Comment: I can't see the 2nd code snippet

Comment: In your view code obtain the GUID and register it with Unity

Comment: If the locator is created in xaml as a resource it must have a default ctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM light and the `ViewModelLocator` you can pass the GUID to it. Once the locator knows the GUID you can register it with the `SimpleIoc` and use it as a dependency.

Comment: The view can register the GUID with the SimpleIoc of MVVM light

Comment: I'm using MVVM light and the **ViewModelLocator** but with the UnityContainer. I think both will work, right? If I understand I should have the constructor of the **ViewModelLocator** receive the GUID parameter. How do I register the GUID in the view. In code-behind? Is it not going to be bound?

Comment: I don't see any use for binding here. When you read the GUID pass it to your locator or IoC container of choice. It seems like a simple and effective solution to me.

Comment: Maybe explain in more detail how you obtain the GUID

Comment: I thought that that was what you were pointing me at when at first you spoke of property injection. I'm sorry but I am getting a bit confused with all of this. If I put a GUID in the locator constructor when it runs I get the exception 'No matching constructor found on type ViewModel.ViewModelLocator'

Comment: Also, who instantiates the locator? Is it a resource?

Comment: I edited my question and pasted the locator code. Although I couldn't past the xaml. It didn't show anything. I don't know how to make it visible

Comment: I see it now. You should be able to register the GUID with Unity in the view code. What's your issue with that?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: How to get the GUID from query string or how to register something using Unity? How about using the MVVM light SimpleIoc? It's very straightforward.

Comment: Look at the RegisterType method of UnityContainer

Comment: I will try to see how it's done and then I'll come back. Thank you both for your trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory via the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).  You'll define a factory interface like so:

```
public interface IFooViewModelFactory
{
    IFooViewModel Create(Guid guid);
}
```

Then add the facility to your Windsor configuration:

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(
                Component.For<IFooViewModelFactory>()
                         .AsFactory()
               );
```

Then rather than just resolving the `IFooViewModel`, you'll resolve `IFooViewModelFactory` and call `Create`:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    readonly IFooViewModelFactory fooViewModelFactory;

    public MainViewModel(IFooViewModelFactory fooViewModelFactory)
    {
        this.fooViewModelFactory = fooViewModelFactory;
    }

    public IFooViewModel CreateFoo(Guid guid)
    {
        return fooViewModelFactory.Create(guid);
    }
}
```

Note that Windsor provides the implementation of the factory, not you.  Also, the factory matches parameters in the constructor with the `Create` method parameters by name, so make sure your `FooViewModel` constructor matches, e.g.:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    // "Guid guid" matches IFooViewModelFactory.Create(Guid guid)
    public FooViewModel(Guid guid)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: He didn't mention Windsor, am i wrong? Anyway the factory idea may serve the purpose

Comment: @dan Wow, you're right, shame on me.  I guess I spent too much time on my own set of tags!

Comment: I don't know what is Windsor or the Typed Factory Facility, maybe a container like the UnityContainer? But anyway I'm still missing how to get the Id from the view to the viewmodel.

Comment: @budahead do it using MVVM light SimpleIoc. Register the GUID and you can use it as a dependency in your VMs

Comment: [Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) is an IOC container, similar to Unity.  If you're not using an IOC container then you can disregard my answer. If you are, there should be a similar construct in your IOC container.  And remember, you're trying to get the Guid from view's _view-model_, not the _view_ itself.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I did not quite understand your last sentence. The only place that I have access to the GUID is in the view through the query string, right? I think I am missing something here ...

Comment: Without seeing your view, it should be bound to a property on some view model.  You then pass it to the view model you're trying to create, which is done in the first view model or somewhere above it.  You didn't post code to say for sure.

Comment: From your view read the GUID and register it in your IoC container. What's the problem?